# mvn command not found only in intellij terminal

Tags: terminal, intellij-idea, pop-os

Just installed pop_os, switched over from MacOS, and I'm having a problem where I can run certain commands in the pop_os terminal window but not within the intellij terminal window.

Trying to run a simple "mvn clean install" in the Intellij terminal window, but i'm told mvn command not found.

In pop_os terminal when I run "which mvn" i'm told that the binary is in "/usr/bin/mvn". When I navigate to that directory in the same terminal window I can see mvn binary is present.. But I navigate to the same directory in intellij terminal window sure enough I cannot see the mvn binary anywhere (surprised_pikachu.png).

Please help?